# get the 3rd word for each element in a character vector

Tags: r, string

I have the following character vector called `strains` :

```
 head(strains, 10)

 [1] "Lactobacillus gasseri APC678"                    "Lactobacillus gasseri DSM 20243"                
 [3] "Bifidobacterium angulatum B677"                  "Bifidobacterium breve Reuter S1"                
 [5] "Lactobacillus reuteri F275"                      "Lactobacillus acidophilus L917"                 
 [7] "Lactobacillus acidophilus 4357"                  "Bifidobacterium pseudocatenulatum B1279"        
 [9] "Bifidobacterium longum subsp. infantis JCM 1210" "Clostridium difficile 43594"
```

What I want to get is a vector with just the 3rd word for each element in the strains. For example, in the element called "Lactobacillus gasseri APC678", I would like to just keep "APC678".

What I did is the following :

```
library(tidyvese)

lapply(strains %>% str_split(" "), '[', 3) %>% unlist
```

Which did the work I want, as you can see in the output my code gives :

```
 [1] "APC678" "DSM"    "B677"   "Reuter" "F275"   "L917"   "4357"   "B1279"  "subsp." "43594"  "subsp." "F275"   "1SL4"   "JCM"   
[15] "JCM"    "AM63"   "DSM"    "L917"   "61D"    "Bb14"   "AM63"   "VPI"
```

However, I'm looking for a **more elegant or concise way** to do the same, maybe using regex or something alike.

---

Here is the `dput` of my data :

```
strains <- c("Lactobacillus gasseri APC678", "Lactobacillus gasseri DSM 20243", 
"Bifidobacterium angulatum B677", "Bifidobacterium breve Reuter S1", 
"Lactobacillus reuteri F275", "Lactobacillus acidophilus L917", 
"Lactobacillus acidophilus 4357", "Bifidobacterium pseudocatenulatum B1279", 
"Bifidobacterium longum subsp. infantis JCM 1210", "Clostridium difficile 43594"
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very simple `word` function from the `stringr` package for this without the need to use regex.

```
library(stringr)

stringr::word(strains, start = 3, end = 3)
 [1] "APC678" "DSM"    "B677"   "Reuter" "F275"   "L917"   "4357"  
 [8] "B1279"  "subsp." "43594"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringr` package:

```
stringr::str_split(strains, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Base R and regex:

```r
sub("^(\\S+\\s){2}(\\S+).*", "\\2", strains)
```

With `data.table`:

```r
data.table::tstrsplit(strains, " ")[[3]]
```

```r
# [1] "APC678" "DSM"    "B677"   "Reuter" "F275"   "L917"   "4357"   "B1279"  "subsp." "43594"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `stringr:match` and capture groups:

```r
library(stringr)

str_match(strains, "(\\S+\\s){2}(\\S+).*")[,3]

#>  [1] "APC678" "DSM"    "B677"   "Reuter" "F275"   "L917"   "4357"   "B1279" 
#>  [9] "subsp." "43594"
```